# Can I use a "displaced" array base in Go?

Tags: arrays, go

I have a problem that would be well solved using a "displaced array base". That is, in C I would set a pointer to array-base + offset, and then access my array using `ptr[x]` which would effectively be `array[offset + x]` but without the extra addition.

Is such a thing possible in Go? From what I've read, I can't find any support for it (including a statement that there is no pointer arithmetic in Go), but with slices and other things that I'm unfamiliar with so far, I'd like a more experienced opinion.

**Edit**

Consider three possible scenarios:

1. I create an array, and want to use some "middle index" of the array as the base:

   ```
   sign_values := { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
   sign := sign + 5
   i = f(x)  // returns [-5 .. 5]
   sign_i = sign[i]
   ```
2. I create an array, and want to use some "negative offset" of the array as the base:

   ```
   to_lower := { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ..., 'z' }
   tolower := to_lower - 'A'

   func ToLower(ch byte) byte {
       if isupper(ch) {
           return tolower[ch]
       }

       return ch
   }
   ```
3. I create an array and want to use some "excessive positive" index as the base. This would be just the same as the others, except with the expectation that all indices were negative. No idea when this would be useful.

In all of the cases, there is a requirement for either a negative index (case 1, case 3), or for a negative offset (case 2). As far as I can tell, this is disallowed at least somewhat by a prohibition on negative indices.

But maybe not?

Comment: Correct, you cannot have a negative index, nor can you change the base offset of an array or slice. You can slice an array, but the slice will always start at index 0 of the slice (though that may not be index 0 of the underlying array).

Answer (score 4):

```
displaced := array[offset:]
```

Just slice it.

[Demo.](https://play.golang.org/p/ec0lsUQaXq)

Comment: Sadly, when I try -2, I get this: `tmp/sandbox009860147/main.go:10: invalid slice index -2 (index must be non-negative)`

Comment: You need to use a positive offset. Look at the linked demo.

Comment: @AustinHastings: No negative indexes.

Comment: If indexes cannot be negative, can the slice use a negative? It seems like this just can't be done...

Comment: @MiloChristiansen If you look, you can see the error message I posted came from the linked demo. ;-)

Comment: The demo has no negative index. I just tried it and it returns `4`. Maybe someone fixed it between your first comment and mine?

Comment: No, I modified it for the purpose.